# Multi part survey - How to make in Laravel 4.0?

Tags: php, checkbox, input, laravel, view

I am currently busy with a application that should work like this:

We have several students that want to take extra classes of a certain subject. So I made a view with 11 subjects they can take. Vary from History, Biology, Geography, etc they can choose what they like. So after choosing a few subjects, I want to take them to the first subject they choose, after that the second, third etc. (they choose the subjects by checkboxes)

I know I have to be working with a cookie if the student is not logged in. And a session if the student needs to login. So, I chose for a login page ofcourse. How do I get the views viewed (in order) that the student has chosen? Do I put it in a controller? Do I use Input? Or set functions in the routes.php file? I would like to have some like this:

```
If checkboxvalue='checked'=>'subject'
{
    then show View('subject');
}
```

It's almost like a multi-part survey, where following views depend greatly on what you selected in the view before it

How to make that in Laravel? Thanks in advance for any tips/advice/link. I really need some help with this

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in the session.

1. The user goes to a route which directs to a controller method: `CourseController::getCourses()`. This method renders a view with a form & a bunch of checkboxes.
2. The user fills out their course selections by checking the checkboxes & submitting. This request is routed to a `postCourses()` method.
3. The `postCourses()` method constructs the list of courses, saves it in the session, and redirects to the page for the first course in the list (eg. `getChem100()`). Imagine you have a list like this: `$courses = array("chem100", "psyc100")`.
4. The `getChem100()` method renders a view. That view includes a "Next" button which posts the form data (whatever they entered for their Chem 100 class) to `postChem100()`.
5. The `postChem100()` method does whatever it needs to do with the data and redirects to the next course in the list (in this case `getPsyc100()`).
6. And so on, until all the data is gathered...

This is a **very minimal** example and there are many ways it could be improved. For example, you'll avoid a lot of duplicate code if you structure your data in such a way that there's only one `getCourseInfo()` method, one view template, and one `postCourseInfo()` method. Those methods would take the course ID as an argument. This kind of optimization will depend on your data structure and is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example Kryten. I've been struggling with this problem for a while. Will try it out, and keep you updated.